# Submitting table-row-ID to following page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table, http-post, footable

I have a functioning table in which I have to fetch row-ID to submit to the following page in which detail data to the table-row is displayed. ID is represented by ID of the mySQL-record.

Actual result is that the ID is not submitted to the following page by Ajax/POST. Actual output:

- POST variable is empty on the following page
- method="post" is defined globally for the whole HTML-body
- redirection to the following page after double-cklick on a table-row is functioning

Table-page (thispage.php):

```
  <table class="table" id="showcase-example-1" data-toggle-column="last" data-paging="true" data-paging-size="15" data-filtering="true" data-sorting="true" data-state="true" data-empty="no records yet">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-sorted="true">Account Name 1</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">Account Name 2</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">Address 1</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">Address 2</th>  
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">ZIP</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs">City</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">State</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Country</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Internet</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">Telephone Fixed Line</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">Line of Business</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">Turnover</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">Number Employees</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">Number Subsidaries</th>
            <th data-breakpoints="xs sm md">Our Competition</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody action="thispage.php">
                    <tr data-expanded="true" type="text" name="recordIDaccounts" class="recordIDaccounts" value="12" ondblclick="window.location.replace('nextpage.php')">
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>Inc.</td>
            <td>Examplestreet</td>
            <td>No. 1</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>Examplecity</td>
            <td>Examplestate</td>
            <td>Examplecountry</td>
            <td>www.internet.com</td>
            <td style="min-width:180px;">+1-123-1234567</td>
            <td>Machinery</td>
            <td>1 Mio.</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Examplecompetition</td>
        </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

//dynamische Tabelle
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
});

//Account-ID des doppelgeklickten Datensatzes auf die Folgeseite übergeben
$('.recordIDaccounts').on('dblclick', 'tr', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = FooTable.getRow(this);
    var value = row.val(); //liefert ein multidimensionales Array mit allen Zeilen-Daten
    var id = this.cells[2].innerHTML; //die ID befindet sich an 3. Position
    var recordIDaccounts = id.toString();
    console.log(recordIDaccounts);
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST", //as well as type: "POST",
        url: "accountsdetails.php",
        data: {recordIDaccounts: recordIDaccounts}        //wenn die Änderung ausgeführt wurde    
    }).done(function(msg){
        //alert("recordIDaccounts übermittelt"); 
    });
});
</script>
```

And here the receiving page where POST-variable keeps empty:

```
<?PHP
//Datensatz-ID des übergebenen Accounts ermitteln
    if(array_key_exists("recordIDaccounts", $_POST)){
        $recordIDaccounts = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['recordIDaccounts']);
    }

echo "Post-ID Datensatz-Nummer -recordIDaccounts-: ".$recordIDaccounts."<br>";
?>
```

Do you have any ideas? I'm working a lot with ajax, but now the first time for submitting a table-row ID ...

Comment: IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Thank you mplungjan. Did you find double ID usage? Even in mySQL every table has unique ID-definition such as tablename_ID ...

Comment: <tr data-expanded="true" type="text" name="recordIDaccounts" id="**recordIDaccounts**"

Comment: ... and the second location? Or do you mean that I should describe name="" and id="" with different values? - What is functioning quite well with same values up to now with other ajax-transmissions. Or do you mean to define name (for POST-method), ID (for ajax-identification) and value (for ajax .val()-method) in an own td-tag?

Comment: Your TRs are in a loop. You use the ID as selector. It will fail if you have more than one row

Comment: That explains the output of the highest table-row-ID-value. Thank you! Do you have a suggestion to solve?

Comment: Use class and $(this).val() or .find

Comment: I changed from id="recordIDaccounts" to class="recordIDaccounts" ==> $('.recordIDaccounts').on('ondblclick', function(). data: {recordIDaccounts: $(this).val()} is not functioning as well as data: {recordIDaccounts: $('.recordIDaccounts').find('td')} is not functioning ...

Comment: Then you need $(“. Instead of $(“#

Comment: ... of course ... - but I already did this when changing from id to class definition ...

Comment: It would be useful if you remove the php and post a [mcve] with only JS and HTML

Comment: I also tried definition of the value in an own td for the ID - maybe I should try this again with your input

Comment: I eliminated the PHP-Code as requested by you, maybe it's now better comprehensible without the value-outsourcing and database-operations ...

Comment: I’ll look after lunch

Comment: Thank you! Have a good meal :-)

Comment: Maybe there is a much better way you are using for such tasks - must really not be my approach which is deriving from my previous experience ...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a table plugin I cannot find any "get" documentation on.

If this works you can ajax the content of the array:

```js
$('.recordIDaccounts').on('dblclick', function() {
  var vals = [];
  $("td", this).each(function() {
    vals.push($(this).text());
  });
  console.log(vals)
  // here you have an array of the textual content of the cells
});
```

Comment: Hi, after some other tasks I went on with this issue and solved how to extract the required value which is now properly reported in the console. I updated the actual code in the initial posting. Although working a lot with ajax the transfer of the value to the following page is not successful, returns undefined variable. So I typecasted the value to String before sending per ajax - but before or after typecasting the result is the same on the following page: undefined variable. Do you have an idea? On the console of the sending page the values are shown correctly.

Comment: No console errors, proper output of the correct ID per double-clicked row. Apache error log has only some entries from the start in the morning, nothing further. This is PHP Error log (echo of the variable in line 1446): [15-Feb-2018 11:32:37 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:

[15-Feb-2018 11:32:37 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() D:\Software\wamp64\www\proficrm\pages\accountsdetails.php:0

[15-Feb-2018 11:32:46 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: recordIDaccounts in D:\Software\wamp64\www\proficrm\pages\accountsdetails.php on line 1446

Comment: This is an excerpt of the Apache access log for a double-click action: ::1 - - [15/Feb/2018:11:53:52 +0100] "GET /proficrm/pages/accounts.php HTTP/1.1" 200 150045
::1 - - [15/Feb/2018:11:53:59 +0100] "POST /proficrm/pages/accountsdetails.php HTTP/1.1" 200 315852
::1 - - [15/Feb/2018:11:53:59 +0100] "GET /proficrm/pages/accountsdetails.php HTTP/1.1" 200 316879

Comment: Could it be the format of the variable value or the ajax data: definition because I normally post HTML-input data ... ?

Comment: I cannot guess. I would not want `Undefined variable: recordIDaccounts` to show in my logfile